# Android studio gradle and jdk version troubleshooting

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have an old project where the Gradle version of 4.4 is used. I tried to build the project in the recent version of the android studio where JDK 11 is used. So, it gives the below error:

```
The project uses Gradle 4.4 which is incompatible with Java 11 or newer.
```

So, I needed to downgrade the JDK version. Changed the jdk version to 8 in the android studio. Because the Gradle dependencies could not be updated as there were a lot of dependencies there. But now the build provides these following error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{layoutlib}' is expected.
```

Is there any solution for that without changing the gradle version as i said there were a lot of dependencies